# Finding embedded DLL resources

Tags: dll, resources, decompiling

I'm using a decompiler to look at a DLL I built a while ago because I don't have the original source anymore.  I want to see what a specfic value for a resource string is, but I can't seem to find them.  I embedded the resource file, so I figured I could just decompile the DLL and see the string, but it isn't anywhere to be found.  Any place I should be checking or is this not possible?

Comment: what language/technology/framework? if .net, you can use reflector.

Comment: .NET C#.  2008.  I tried D# but couldn't find the values anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using Reflector and saw what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Would a tool like [XN Resource Editor](http://www.wilsonc.demon.co.uk/d10resourceeditor.htm) work for you?